# Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header() during downloading file

Tags: laravel

I want to download a file but whenever I try to download it it's showing this error:

> Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header()

```
@if($document->file)
    <td>
        <a href="{{route('file.download',$document->file)}}"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-outline-warning">{{$document->file}}</button></a> 
    </td>
@endif
```

routes:

```
Route::get('/employee/file/download/{file}','ErpEmployeeController@fileDownload')->name('file.download');
```

controller:

```
public function fileDownload($file)
{
    $files = public_path() . "/uploads/file/" . $file;

    return response()->file($files);
}
```

Comment: if you want a download you should use `response()->download($files);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a download you should use the `download()` function:

```
response()->download($files);
```

Comment: please comsider accepting and upvoting the answer if it works

Comment: that wasn't the problem. problem is i have to edit this Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header() function. answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429829/call-to-undefined-method-symfony-component-httpfoundation-binaryfileresponsehe

Comment: The question you posted explain that the error on the download occur only when a user middleware that overwrite response headers is active, have you some kind of middlware active?